# How to use build for adding to ActiveRecord collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model called PhoneItems which has many CallingTimes.
To disable the has_many autosave functionality I had to start using the build method.

```
phone_queue_items.calling_times.build
```

so that when the edit form is closed, the calling time isn't automatically saved. Now I have the following problem. I want to be able to push a second calling_time to the PhoneItem object, however the following is not working:

```
phone_queue_items.calling_times << CallingTimes.build
```

nor
    phone_queue_items.calling_times.build

Is there any way to do build more than one calling time in the phone_queue_item object?

Comment: You can pass an array as well like `phone_queue_items.calling_items << [call_times_1, call_times_2, call_times_3]`

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new object, and push it to the array:

```
phone_queue_items.calling_times << CallingTimes.new
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `build` multiple times on the collection, and each item will be added and ready for saving.

```
2.times { phone_queue_items.calling_times.build }
phone_queue_items.calling_times
#=> [#<CallingTime...>, #<CallingTime...>]
```